# how to create table using multiple dimensional array in php

Tags: php

Actually This are my real data from API.

```php
$main2 = array(
    'sup1' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TATA'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 10, "source_type" => 'Rel'),
    ),
    'sup2' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TCS'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 55, "source_type" => 'Jio'),
    ),
);
```

We need same out put using this array.

we create table all date in header like first key date as display in header.
-then data display supplier sup1 in first row
 sup2 in second row row

like below out put

```
|Supplier Name  |01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019 |04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019|<br/>
|sup1|54|TATA|10|Rel|
<br/>
|sup2|54|TCS|55|JIO|
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified:

```php
<?php
$main2 = array(
    '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array(
        'sup1' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TATA'),
        'sup2' => array("connection_count" => 10, "source_type" => 'Rel'),
    ),
    '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array(
        'sup1' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TCS'),
        'sup2' => array("connection_count" => 55, "source_type" => 'Jio'),
    ),
);
$suplist = array('sup1', 'sup2');

echo "<table border=1><tr>";
echo "<td>Supplier Name</td>";

foreach ($main2 as $key => $value) {
    echo "<td colspan=2>" . $key . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach ($suplist as $supplier) {
    echo "<tr><td>$supplier</td>";
    foreach ($main2 as $value) {
        echo "<td>" . $value[$supplier]['connection_count'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value[$supplier]['source_type'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

And here is sample output (reformatted for clarity):

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier Name</td>
    <td colspan=2>01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019</td>
    <td colspan=2>04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sup1</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>TATA</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sup2</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Rel</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>Jio</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is your code which works with updated input data format:

```php
$main2 = array(
    'sup1' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TATA'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 10, "source_type" => 'Rel'),
    ),
    'sup2' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TCS'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 55, "source_type" => 'Jio'),
    ),
);

$suppliers = array_keys($main2);

$dateRanges = [];
foreach ($main2 as $supplierData) {
    $dateRanges = array_merge($dateRanges, array_keys($supplierData));
}
$dateRanges = array_values(array_unique($dateRanges));
sort($dateRanges);

echo "<table border=1><tr>";
echo "<td>Supplier Name</td>";

foreach ($dateRanges as $dateRange) {
    echo "<td colspan=2>" . $dateRange . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach ($suppliers as $supplier) {
    echo "<tr><td>$supplier</td>";
    foreach ($dateRanges as $dateRange) {
        if (isset($main2[$supplier][$dateRange])) {
            echo "<td>" . $main2[$supplier][$dateRange]['connection_count'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $main2[$supplier][$dateRange]['source_type'] . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td></td><td></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

And here is sample output (formatted for clarity):

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Supplier Name</td>
    <td colspan=2>01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019</td>
    <td colspan=2>04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sup1</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>TATA</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Rel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sup2</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>TCS</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>Jio</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If i am removed this array $suplist = array('sup1', 'sup2'); 
Then how to print same layout any idea ? Actually i am getting only dynamic   aaray not a suplist array.

Comment: No idea because I don't know how your data looks. If you can provide a sample of input data, I might be able to provide a code that outputs a table.

Comment: Actually This are my real data from API.

$main2 = array(
    'sup1' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TATA'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 10, "source_type" => 'Rel'),
    ),
    'sup2' => array(
        '01-Jun-2019-TO-03-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 54, "source_type" => 'TCS'),
        '04-Jun-2019-TO-08-Jun-2019' => array("connection_count" => 55, "source_type" => 'Jio'),
    ),
);

We need same out put using this array.

Comment: Could you show a little bit more effort and adds this code to your original question nicely formatted? Thank you.

Comment: we added my actual array in main question. I am not able to formatted code . bcz i am new on stack overflow.